# I want to know why Blender 3.2.2 on my laptop seemingly crashes when a custom shader is used, when other PC set ups were tried and worked fine

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine

My specs are a laptop with 16 GB of ram, an 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i5-1135G7 processor (2.40 GHz, up to 4.20 GHz, 8M Cache), and Intel® Iris® Xe Graphics. Only Blender itself seems to crash, and it usually gets a couple colors on the model before becoming frozen and unresponsive. I am using EEVEE render engine, and am relatively new to Blender.

Comment: Have you submitted a bug/crash report? The devs are usually pretty responsive with issues. Have you tried making sure your video drivers are up to date?

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/troubleshooting/crash.html

Comment: Jakemoyo, about to do that now, if I can figure out where and how to do that.

and Harry, thank you for the link, about to check it out.